# How to Routing using Linux Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: windows-7, linux

how to routing using Ubuntu Linux 11.10 that IP address can ping class A to class C ? one client using Windows Operating system and the other using Linux ubuntu 11.10. I can configure it, please help me. thank you

Comment: I'll need more information. I just read up on [classful networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network), but that doesn't help me answer your question. Who's trying to ping who?

Comment: Classful addressing basically doesn't exist any more except on Cisco certification exams. It's dead in the real world. VLSM and CIDR made it obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 network cards in the system, first off.  I'm also assuming the following:

- you mean the private IPv4 ranges in Class A and C.
- you're assigning IP addresses to the machines manually for an experminent.

First nic needs an address/netmask in 10.0.0.0/8 (Class A) - I'd say 10.0.0.1/255.255.255.0 is good.  Use `ifconfig` (from a root terminal) to assign it.  Machines behind this need to have an IP address in the range of 10.0.0.2 through 10.1.1.254, with netmask 255.255.255.0.

Second nic needs an address in 192.168.0.0/24 (Class C) - I'd say 192.168.0.1 is good.  Use `ifconfig` (from a root terminal) to assign it.  Machines behind this need to have an IP address in the range of 192.168.0.2 through 192.168.0.254, with netmask 255.255.255.0.

Cool, now we have 2 interfaces and 2 subnets, the minimum needed for routing.  To enable IP forwarding, i.e. routing, in Linux, use the following command (from a root terminal)

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

You'll have to do that on each reboot, unless you edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` (as root).

One final detail, is that you want the firewall completely down, at least until you confirm forwarding is working.  The following commands (as root) will disable any packet filtering or manipulation from `iptables`:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

After that, network traffic should be forwarded between the two interfaces assuming all machines have proper addresses.  The kernel's FIB will be populated with information from the interfaces and you can look at it with the `route` command.

If you want to limit what is forwarded, delve deeper into `iptables`.

A last thought: remember that routers do NOT pass broadcast traffic, such as DHCP requests.

Comment: I mean my notebook become a router, then another notebook connecting using wired and wireless from my notebook. I had been configure the IP adrees like that, but still not working. do I must install another software???

Comment: The above needs to be performed no matter what type of nic the nic is (wireless, ppp, virtual, etc.).  On a wireless nic you need make sure it's in ad-hoc mode (for laptop-laptop connection) and associated with the other laptop first, use `iwconfig` before doing any of the above.